# Why FirebaseAnalytics can't see real devices?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I needed to reconnect Firebase to a new project, I did everything according to the instructions. The package is correct, the file is replaced, the libraries are connected

```
dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:18.0.2'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

google()
```

In MainActivity, I also connected everything, it seems that there is nothing more required.

```
private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics
```

The problem is that FirebaseAnalytics sees emulators, but does not see real devices, not the one on which I am testing, not from users. Not in debug not in release mode. Can you please tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: The ```google()``` makes it look like you added ```implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:18.0.2'``` to your *project gradle*, not the *app gradle*. Is that the case?

Comment: @Amin No, I just wanted to show that I added everything that is in the instructions, everything in the project is in place